# NSDictionary frome one key to many

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I got NSDictionary

```
Printing description of gameDict:
{
    result =     {
        developer = "Bethesda Game Studios";
        genre = "Role-Playing";
        name = "The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim";
        platform = "PlayStation 3";
        publisher = "Bethesda Softworks";
        rating = M;
        rlsdate = "2011-11-11";
        score = 92;
        summary = "The next chapter in the Elder Scrolls saga arrives from the Bethesda Game Studios. Skyrim reimagines the open-world fantasy epic, bringing to life a complete virtual world open for you to explore any way you choose. Play any type of character you can imagine, and do whatever you want; the legendary freedom of choice, storytelling, and adventure of The Elder Scrolls is realized like never before. Skyrim's new game engine brings to life a complete virtual world with rolling clouds, rugged mountains, bustling cities, lush fields, and ancient dungeons. Choose from hundreds of weapons, spells, and abilities. The new character system allows you to play any way you want and define yourself through your actions. Battle ancient dragons like you've never seen. As Dragonborn, learn their secrets and harness their power for yourself.";
        thumbnail = "http://static.metacritic.com/images/products/games/6/372529409ea6cc3faadf5674fd96ba2a-98.jpg";
        url = "http://www.metacritic.com/game/playstation-3/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim";
        userscore = "6.3";
    };
}
```

It got only one key "result" 
How can i get other keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gameDict is an NSDictionary with one key/pair. The key "result" points to another NSDictionary which has lots more keys. So to access any of the deeper keys you can either do it inline:

```
NSNumber *score = gameDict[@"result"][@"score"];
```

Or you can pull out the Dictionary and query it

```
NSDictionary *resultDict = gameDict[@"result"];
NSNumber *score = resultDict[@"score"];
```

Comment: Thank u a lot, sorry cant up ur rep coz my is low